# Gitlab not ordering repos by commit date

Tags: gitlab, git-commit

We've started migrating repos from an old gogs instance to gitlab web. However, after mirroring the projects (by using git clone --mirror), gitlab orders the projects by creation date, rather than last commit. So we have multiple repositories, all with different last commit dates, but shown within two hours of each other since we pushed them to gitlab one after the other.

For instance:

- Gitlab shows "Updated 3 hours ago"
- Gogs shows "Updated 1 month ago"

Any way to change Gitlab so that it shows the commit date, rather than the project creation date?